# Javascript does not assign CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
            var corX = subEvent.clientX;
            var corY = subEvent.clientY;
            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute("id", corX + "," + corX);
            x.setAttribute("src", "pin.png");
            x.setAttribute("width", "20");
            x.setAttribute("height", "20");


            x.style.left = corX + "px";
            x.style.top = corY + "px";
            x.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
            x.style.zIndex = "-1";
            document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Here is my code snippet of interest, I am trying to add images on the user's click to an image. These images I am adding are added dynamically. When I do an alert on the changes, they do appear changed, zIndex is -1, left is what ever it should be... I tried setAttribute for style but it does not work, and does not change the values. Furthermore I am testing this on IE7, not any higher.

Comment: The element is not absolutely positioned.

Comment: *"Furthermore I am testing this on IE7..."* You poor sod. :-) You're really working on a project that requires supporting IE7? In 2017?

Comment: I don't think the style ```transform``` will work in IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't position an element outside of the normal "flow" of the document unless you explicitly take it out of the flow. `position:absolute` will position the element with respect to its nearest ancestor that has had its position explicitly set (or body if none), `position:relative` will position the element relative to its original position in the document and `position:fixed` will position it exactly where you want and then it won't scroll with the rest of the document.

```js
var corX = "100";
var corY = "100";

var x = document.createElement("IMG");
// Take the element out of the normal "flow"
x.style.position = "absolute";

x.setAttribute("id", corX + "," + corX);
x.setAttribute("src", "pin.png");
x.setAttribute("width", "20");
x.setAttribute("height", "20");

x.style.left = corX + "px";
x.style.top = corY + "px";
x.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
x.style.zIndex = "-1";
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: I did, how ever my reputation is too low for it to show because I am new. I did give you an upvote.